# Dynamic color mouse cursor on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, mouse-cursor

As far as I can tell the mouse cursor color can only be set to a static one. This is not great at all, it would be much better visibility wise if it would react to whatever it is on the screen under it. I am aware of the potential computational complexity but it's not 1995 any more. Google has nothing. Is there a modern solution anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, perhaps since '95 (or 3.1??), the mouse pointer (cursor) can be set to *inverted*, i.e., anti-camouflage. On a black background, it's white, and *versa vice* [sic].

[image: Invert mouse cursor coloring]

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type *ease of*.
- Select *Ease of Access display settings*.
- Select *Mouse pointer*.
- In *Change pointer color*, select the harlequin, inverting image.

You can also use *animated cursors* for even more eye-catching effect, such as [these](https://www.cursors-4u.com/animated/). There are even [animated inverting cursors](https://www.cursors-4u.com/cursor/2009/11/25/color-inverting-mouse-pointer.html).

The mouse can also be made to [leave a trail](https://winaero.com/enable-pointer-trails-windows-10/) (mouse droppings?).

Comment: I somehow missed that . Thanks. It gets weird here and there but it's far better than the often invisible cursor I struggled with.

Comment: Windows also has mouse cursor trails; no third-party tool needed: https://accessibility.shell.com/windows-10-adding-trails-your-mouse-pointer

Answer (score 2):

Stardock has a cursor customizing package known as [cursorFX](https://www.stardock.com/products/cursorfx/).

It's not a free program but there is a free trial available. At US$4.00, it's not particularly expensive.

> Quickly change the size, color or drop shadow of any cursor from the
> settings menu. Personalize your mouse clicks with cool sounds effects.
> Add a unique visual style to your cursors by applying different
> combinations of special effects and motion trails that are included
> with CursorFX.

[image: stardock cursorFX color settings]

Image from linked site

Comment: Thanks I will test this. Their trailer mentions sound effects which makes me real curious.